# Trying to communicate with an external board through Arduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I'm trying to communicate with and send commands to an [external board](http://airqualityegg.wikispaces.com/file/view/micsuserguide.pdf) (page 23) from an Arduino. For some reason, which I can't figure out, the external board acknowledges my serial commands intermittently.

I noticed that the Arduino board I'm working with is 5V and the TX/RX communication on the external board is designed for 3.3V. Could this be the cause of the intermittent response from the external board?

Comment: Everyone is assuming this is an electrical problem, but I wouldn't rule out software problems - it's very easy to write embedded serial code which will drop messages, not listen while it is talking, etc.

Comment: The strange thing is, when I connected the Arduino pins straight to the TX/RX pins on the MSP430, and looked at the signal received by the MSP430 from the Arduino in an Oscilloscope (compared to ground), it registered peak to peak voltage as 3.6V with the MSP plugged in (it registered 4 V without the MSP plugged in). When I removed the pin from the MSP, I got 5V, which makes sense since the Arduino operates on 5V. It seems like there is some dissipation also on the microcontroller or on other components on the external board that causes the voltage to drop. Is that estimation plausible?

Comment: Are you connecting directly to the Serial RXD and Serial TXD pins on Expansion Port PL2 of the sensor eval kit? How can you be sure of the baud rate, parity, etc. for these pins? The schematic on p. 23 is pretty worthless, by the way.

Comment: I just tried a 3.3V Arduino Pro 328P. Now it´s giving me a consistent output. So it seems to be working. I had tried to put in a voltage divider down to 3.3 with three 10k resistors, but that didn't work, I thought there might be some dissipation in the microcontroller. For some reason, the 3.3V Arduino works, I'm not really sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best not to over engineer anything here. Just use a voltage divider. Arduino uses 5V, MSP uses 3.3V. So... 5V*20k/(10k+20k) = 3.3V. However, MSP is powered at 3.3V...so use something like 5V*10k/(10k+10k) = 2.5V. What this means is that you need to connect the Arduino's Tx line to voltage divider to MSP's Rx line. From MSP's Tx line to Arduino's Rx line, no need for voltage divider because it's only 3.3V. Done.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum voltage that can be applied at any pin on the MSP430 is only 0V3 above Vcc; trying to feed it 5V could be damaging it. Additionally, 3V3 is *just* below the typical threshold for a high input for 5V CMOS (3V5). You should consider using a voltage convertor on both pins in order to reduce possible issues.

Answer (score 0):

The msp430f2616 has no 5v Tolerant pins. At 3.3v VCC, anything above 3.6v (Vcc + 0.3) can damage it. On the flip side, the Arduino's ATmega328 has a Voltage Input High Level minimum of 0.6 * VCC, which on the Arduino is 5v. That means you need 3v to register as a logic high on an input pin. So you might get one way communication, but since you possibly damaged the MSP430, and the voltage out of the msp430 depends on the current on the port causing voltage sag, you would be hard press to get a stable signal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure its been answered before but I can't resist the circuit editor.

A simple FET level shifter, one needed per channel/line. Don't forget to tie the GND's together.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPBNvN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>